# Trajectory of falling object, with and without initial velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-fall

If an object is dropped from a roof with no initial velocity and wind is blowing along the side of the building exerting a constant force on the object, then its trajectory will be a straight line. But if the object has an initial velocity downwards, then its trajectory will be a parabola instead (according to my book). I don't understand why!

Why does it not just become a steeper straight line? It will still have the same vertical and horizontal accelerations right?

Comment: There is something wrong with the stated problem, not with how you understand it. It makes no sense that the path is straight down in the first case, with a constant force from a side.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a straight line, but with an angle! Edited the text :)

Comment: In the second case: Just any velocity downwards in the second case, or some specific - like maybe terminal velocity, so that there is no further acceleration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If velocity does not change direction, the object will travel in a straight line.

In the zero initial velocity scenario, with constant force (and therefore acceleration) from wind in the horizontal direction, and constant force (and therefore acceleration) from gravity in the downward direction, there is net constant acceleration in a particular direction (the vector sum of the two accelerations).  Starting from zero velocity and accelerating in a particular direction means velocity never changes direction and motion is in a straight line.

Instead, if there is an initial velocity in the downward direction, velocity and acceleration are not in the same direction.  Initially, motion would be downward, but become increasingly in the same direction as acceleration.